# Why the flycheck fringe icon show half in right fringe

Tags: emacs, flycheck

New come to emacs. i config flycheck the icon but i found a problem that it only show a half.
[image]

Comment: The fringe looks too narrow to display the fringe bitmap. The default fringe bitmap is of width 8 I think. To test eval `(fringe-mode 8)` to make the fringes wider. Press `M-S-;` to eval that expression.

Comment: `M-:` to eval an expression (same but the other way it is confusing)